# Using jsonp in nodejs and origin ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, jsonp

I'm trying to know how jsonp work, so I wrote a demo working on nodejs, without jQuery. But, it was not working.
Bellow was my code:

---

views/index.jade

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title Demo of jsonp
  body
    #result
    script.
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var url = '/getjsonp?callback=abc'

      function abc (data) {
        alert('aaa')
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = data.name;
      }

      xhr.open('GET', url);
      xhr.send();
```

---

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();
var data = { name: 'jacket', company: 'fdd' };

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views/'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});

app.get('/getjsonp', function (req, res, next) {
  var callback = req.query.callback;
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/javascript' });
  res.end(callback + '(' + JSON.stringify(data) + ')');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

---

And here is the response:

```
abc({"name":"jacket","company":"fdd"})
```

As my expect, I define a method abc() in index.jade, then request '/getjsonp?callback=abc' by async ajax, it'll response a javascript which will execute the method: abc().
But it was not working like that, I dont know anywhere was wrong, hope you can tell me if you know.
Thanks!

Comment: Please simplify your life by using expressjs or koajs in node.js

Comment: Thanks Joe, I simplify my code by using express and jade, but it still not working.@JoeTannoury

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that everything is working here, it's just that in the client, you'll need to retrieve the data sent back from the server using:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        eval(xhr.responseText);
    }
};
```

hope this helps :)

**NOTE**: eval will make a string like "abc({a: 'a'})" to running the function abc with a parameter with 1 argument (which is the object {a: 'a'}

Answer (score 0):

And I found another way to make it work without ajax:

```
<script>
   function abc (data) {
    alert('aaa')
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = data.name;
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/getjsonp?callback=abc"></script>
```